# Выровнять содержимое блока div по нижнему краю

Tags: css

Есть блок div, в нем содержимое. Как прижать это содержимое к низу блока?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  width: 500px;
  display: table;
  min-height: 250px;
  background: red;
}
div p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Текст, текст, текст, текст, текст, текст</p>
</div>
```

[Пример на JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3rjy/)

Answer (score 2):

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

div{
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 250px;
    background: #00f;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative; 
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
div p{
    position: absolute; bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>    
    <p>Текст, текст, текст, текст, текст, текст</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MjZ2g/